# Wallis' derivation of information entropy

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

In Wallis' combinatorial derivation of the information entropy (see [here](https://michael-franke.github.io/intro-data-analysis/the-maximum-entropy-principle.html) or [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy#The_Wallis_derivation), the text is copied down below), I don't understand what the information $I$ is in

> If it happens to conform to the information $I$, we accept it;

it seems very vague to me...

**full text**

> A second and perhaps more intuitive approach to deriving entropy was
> suggested by $G$. Wallis. We are given information $I$, which is to be
> used in assigning probabilities $\{p_1,...,p_m\}$ to $m$
>
> different probabilities. We have a total amount of probability
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^m p_i=1$$
>
> to allocate among them.
>
> The problem can be stated as follows. Choose some integer $n>>m$ , and
> imagine that we have $n$ little quanta of probabilities, each of
> magnitude $\delta=\frac1n,$
>
> to distribute in a way we see fit.
>
> Suppose we were to scatter these quanta at random among the $m$
> choices (penny-pitch game into $m$
>
> equal boxes). If we simply toss these quanta of probability at random,
> so that each box has an equal probability of getting them, nobody can
> claim that any box is being unfairly favored over any other.
>
> If we do this and the first box receives exactly $n_1$ quanta, the
> second $n_2$ quanta etc., we will say the random experiment has
> generated the probability assignment:
>
> $$p_i=n_iδ=\frac{n_i}{n},\text{ with }i=1,2,...,m.$$
>
> The probability that this will happen is the multinomial distribution:
>
> $$m^{−n}n!n_1!⋅...⋅n_m!$$
>
> Now imagine that we repeatedly scatter the $n$ quanta at random among
> the m boxes. Each time we do this we examine the resulting probability
> assignment. If it happens to conform to the information $I$, we accept
> it; otherwise, we reject it and try again. We continue until some
> probability assignment $\{p_1,...,p_m\}$
>
> is accepted.
>
> What is the most likely probability distribution to result from this
> game? It is the one which maximizes
>
> $$W=n!n_1!⋅...⋅n_m!$$
>
> subject to whatever constraints are imposed by the information $I$.
>
> We can refine this procedure by using smaller quanta, i.e., large $n$.
> By using Stirling’s approximation
>
> $$n!∼\sqrt{2πn}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n,$$
>
> and taking the logarithm from it
>
> $$log(n!)∼\sqrt{2πn}+nlog\left(\frac{n}{e}\right),$$
>
> we have
>
> $$log(n!)∼\sqrt{2πn}+nlog(n)−n.$$
>
> Taking furthermore, also the logarithm from W and substituting
> $log(n!)$
>
> by Stirling’s approximation, finally gives the definition of
> information entropy, as derived by Shannon’s theorem:
>
> $$\frac1n log(W)\to \sum_{i=1}^m p_i log(p_i)=H(p_1,...,p_m)$$.
>
> To sum it up: Entropy is a measure of uncertainty. The higher the
> entropy of a random variable X , the more uncertainty it incorporates.
> When the goal is to find a maximal ignorance distribution, this goal
> can be consequently translated into a maximization problem: Find the
> distribution with maximal entropy subject to existing constraints.
> This will be the topic of the next section.

Comment: I think that he is trying to find the probability distribution that verifies some specification, or some set of constraints, which he calls "the information $I$"; and he does that through the procedure he describes. A distribution "conforms to the information $I$" if it verifies the constraints defined by $I$. For instance, the "information $I$" could be "the expected value of $x_1, \dots, x_m$ under the probability is $\bar x$". It is indeed a bit vague. One problem is that it is unclear whether a given "information $I$" will result in a unique choice of distribution.